# Adding nameservers to kubernetes

Tags: dns, kubernetes

I'm using Kubernetes v1.0.6 on AWS that has been deployed using `kube-up.sh`.
Cluster is using `kube-dns`.

```
$ kubectl get svc kube-dns --namespace=kube-system
NAME       LABELS                                                                           SELECTOR           IP(S)       PORT(S)
kube-dns   k8s-app=kube-dns,kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true,kubernetes.io/name=KubeDNS   k8s-app=kube-dns   10.0.0.10   53/UDP
```

Which works fine.

```
$ kubectl exec busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.0.0.10
Address 1: 10.0.0.10 ip-10-0-0-10.eu-west-1.compute.internal

Name:      kubernetes.default
Address 1: 10.0.0.1 ip-10-0-0-1.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

This is the `resolv.conf` of a pod.

```
$ kubectl exec busybox -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.0.0.10
nameserver 172.20.0.2
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

Is it possible to have the containers use an additional nameserver?

I have a secondary DNS based service discovery Oon let's say 192.168.0.1) that I would like my kubernetes containers to be able to use for dns resolution.

ps. A kubernetes 1.1 solution would also be acceptable :)

Thank you very much in advance,
George

Comment: A safe way to maybe do this would be adding the nameserver in skydns' configuration, just not sure how this would be done when automating the cluster creation/upgrading via `kube-up/push`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually managed to solve this pretty easily by configuring SkyDNS to add an additional nameserver, you can just add the environmental variable `SKYDNS_NAMESERVERS` as defined in the [SkyDNS docs](https://github.com/skynetservices/skydns#environment-variables) in your SkyDNS replication controller. It has minimal impact and does not depend on node changes etc.

```
    env:
    - name: SKYDNS_NAMESERVERS
      value: 10.0.0.254:53,10.0.64.254:53
```

Comment: Hey, is there a way to add/set/modify this environment variable without having to define the entire kube-dns replication controller myself?

Answer (score 2):

The [DNS addon README](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b9cfab87e33ea649bdd13a1bd243c502d76e5d22/cluster/addons/dns/README.md#inheriting-dns-from-the-node) has some details on this. Basically, the pod will inherit the `resolv.conf` setting of the node it is running on, so you could add your extra DNS server to the nodes' `/etc/resolv.conf`. The `kubelet` also takes a [`--resolv-conf` argument](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/69a8dc64c72b6268ebeb8cd03493aa219643a79d/cmd/kubelet/app/server.go#L284) that may provide a more explicit way for you to inject the extra DNS server. I don't see that flag documented anywhere yet, however.

Comment: Is there a way to automate either of these processes or make them part of kube-up/kube-push in a way that future updates to them will not break everything?

Comment: Additionally, adding extra nameservers to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` will indeed have them show up in the containers' `/etc/resolv.conf` files, but since the first two nameservers that kube injects are up and running, the new ones will never be queried.

Comment: I don't use the `kube-up.sh` process anymore, so take what I say with a grain of salt (yeah, I just made a pun). But I think to automate this you'd probably have to maintain an altered version of the Salt template at `cluster/saltbase/salt/kubelet/default` that sets the desired option for `master_kubelet_args`. Might not be ideal over the long term, but might help while you see if it is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Kuberenetes (probably) 1.2 we'll be moving to a model where `nameservers` are assumed to be fungible.  There are too many resolvers that break when different nameservers serve different subsets of DNS, and there is no real specification here that we can point to.

In other words, we'll start dropping the host's nameserver records from the container's merged resolv.conf and making our own DNS server the only `nameserver` line.  Our DNS will be able to forward requests to upstream nameservers.

Comment: how then can we ensure the dns service is always 100% up? At the moment if we kill one of the dns pods, it takes time for the dns service to reflect it so some dns queries fail and cause apps to crash (why is a different discussion, but we don't control the apps). I had in mind to have two dns services in k8s so that both servers can be used by the container, even if one returns a failure the other one should pick up, is there a better approach?

Comment: You can run multiple replicas of your DNS server, but you can't run multiple "different" DNS servers and expect them to work, unless they have the same data.

Comment: true, but you can make both servers have the same data... I now run kube-dns with two services on 10.3.0.10 and 10.3.0.11. Each service has one or more pod replicas, it does not really matter. This has solved our dns issue because when a pod is relocated, some requests fail during the transition but then the OS of the client pod tries the other server and the app does not see a failure. The problem we have it to let the kubelet give these two nameservers to the pod. I considered serving the entire resolv.conf but then we would miss the search fields that are depending on the namespace.

Comment: The current model with a single dns server is really not working well if the apps are sensitive to dns failures, specially with some resolvers like musl in alpine. It is very easy to reproduce if you want I'll file an issue with code samples

Comment: Question, can I create a custom resolv.conf of my own with maybe 8.8.8.8 and my kube dns service ip and use that?

Comment: There is not a way, currently, to manually configure resolv.conf for a Pod.  @caiman - I am curious why multiple services with different IPs is different from multiple replicas?  Is it simply because some resolvers will try them in parallel?  I am very interested in things we can do to make DNS more resilient and reliable.

Comment: @TimHockin with several name servers configured, some resolvers will try the next server if the first one fails (or in parallel indeed). Two services, each set as a separate name server, was a good workaround for us at the time I posted the comment, when kube-proxy was broken for udp in hyperkube. Killing a dns pod would then cause a long outage.  This has been fixed in the meantime by https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/26839 so we are not using that workaround any more and back to a single service.

Comment: Hi Tim, this doesn't seem to work in VMWare Ubuntu images for some reason. VMWare decided to serve dns via some virtual setup (no idea what they do honestly), but kubernetes can't pick that up. Being able to add another nameserver would be great in such a strange setup as well.

Comment: @TimHockin I take back what I just said. [This blogpost](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/04/configuring-private-dns-zones-upstream-nameservers-kubernetes.html) actually solves all the problems one could have. Really thanks for that. The only problem left is that it is quite hard to find such gems of engineering and documentation. ;)

Answer (score 1):

For those usign Kubernetes `kube-dns`, flag `-nameservers` nor environment variable `SKYDNS_NAMESERVERS` are no longer avaiable.

```
Usage of /kube-dns:
  --alsologtostderr                  log to standard error as well as files
  --config-map string                config-map name. If empty, then the config-map will not used. Cannot be  used in conjunction with federations flag. config-map contains dynamically adjustable configuration.
  --config-map-namespace string      namespace for the config-map (default "kube-system")
  --dns-bind-address string          address on which to serve DNS requests. (default "0.0.0.0")
  --dns-port int                     port on which to serve DNS requests. (default 53)
  --domain string                    domain under which to create names (default "cluster.local.")
  --healthz-port int                 port on which to serve a kube-dns HTTP readiness probe. (default 8081)
  --kube-master-url string           URL to reach kubernetes master. Env variables in this flag will be expanded.
  --kubecfg-file string              Location of kubecfg file for access to kubernetes master service; --kube-master-url overrides the URL part of this; if neither this nor --kube-master-url are provided, defaults to service account tokens
  --log-backtrace-at traceLocation   when logging hits line file:N, emit a stack trace (default :0)
  --log-dir string                   If non-empty, write log files in this directory
  --log-flush-frequency duration     Maximum number of seconds between log flushes (default 5s)
  --logtostderr                      log to standard error instead of files (default true)
  --stderrthreshold severity         logs at or above this threshold go to stderr (default 2)
  -v, --v Level                      log level for V logs
  --version version[=true]           Print version information and quit
  --vmodule moduleSpec               comma-separated list of pattern=N settings for file-filtered logging
```

Now, either you put your name servers on the hosts `resolv.conf`, so DNS is inherited from the node, or you use custom `resolv.conf` and add it to Kubelet with the flag `--resolv-conf` as explained [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/dns/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the IP of your Core DNS to set it as a secondary DNS

Run this command to get the CoreDNS IP:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get svc
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns         ClusterIP   172.20.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   43d
metrics-server   ClusterIP   172.20.232.147   <none>        443/TCP         43d
```

This is how I setup DNS in my deployment yaml.

I posted the Google DNS IP (for clarity) and my CoreDNS ip, but you should use your VPC DNS and your CoreDNS server.

```
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      dnsPolicy: None
      dnsConfig:
        nameservers:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 172.20.0.10
        searches:
          - 1b.svc.cluster.local
          - svc.cluster.local
          - cluster.local
          - ec2.internal
        options:
          - name: ndots
            value: "5"
```